# After "Default" animation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to add some animation after my Default.png is no longer necessary. I know that I will do it in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but my question what format animation should be and how to load it?

There is a plenty app with beautiful animations right after default. But i can't figure out how it works.

For example: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bump/id305479724?mt=8 this is what i want to do. First static png, but when my app will be in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` i want to do some animated stuff like in Bump. How can i do that?

Yes, i know i didn't try anything so far, but i really don't know where to start it.

Comment: What kind of animation? Did you try anything?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You can use a lot of animations, core animation, OpenGL and so on. And it can be launched not only on `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but, also on `viewDidLoad` on your first view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on your demands. If you want to load a video already done, take a look at [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html)
If you want to just create animations from objects of your design you can study a little from [core animation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/introduction/introduction.html) I won't explain everything because as you will see.. it's a lot of documentation for it. You can even create your OpenGL animations and play it.

You can start your vid, on your `viewDidLoad` in the first view, after the splash screen disappears.

EDIT: a nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial).